# Drupal 8 hook_update_n code example needed

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

We have an existing custom module for our Drupal 8 application that created a content type and a view. The "news" module is in our production environment running fine; many pieces of content have been created using it.

Now enhancements have been requested: 2 new fields and a change to the view. I have made the changes using the admin UI in our dev environment, but I will need to put these changes into the module's code for version control so that in new site instances, one need not remember to make UI changes after installing the module.

```
The fields:
field_show_on_page, Field Type: List (text)
field_news_dateline, Field Type: Date
View:
The change in the view is on what field the sorting is done.
```

It would be simple to export the fields and view configurations and add them to the module>config >install folder, but for the change to be picked up, that requires uninstalling and reinstalling the module, which can't be done without needing to delete news content, which is not acceptable.

I understand the changes can be done in hook_update_N in the news.install file. But I cannot find examples for this function that is close enough for this need. I understand the function should be written as:

```
news_update_8001() {}
```

but what would go in the body to add the two fields and update the view?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the new fields in your config you can just delete the old fields by adding this in your hook and then run drush updb before you import the config:

```
$field = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('field_config')->load('node.news.old_field');
if ($field) {
    $field->delete();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I do not need to delete any fields, just add two new ones. Is there a way to add the field configurations and refer to them in the hook_update_N to be picked up? Is that how it's done?
Also, how is a view updated?

Comment: Are you using features or drupal config import/export?

Comment: I am using export for the two fields and view.

Comment: Check your config files to see if the new fields you have added are there. And upon importing this config the new fields should be created.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Through the UI, I created the two new fields. I export their configurations. I just tried adding those configuration files to the install directory of the module. But drush updb does not pick up the change. Did I miss a step?

Comment: Ah, with another contrib module, I was able to find the needed code to refer to the new configuration and install it. Still need to find an example for updating the view in code.

Comment: The metatag module was also helpful for guidance. Thank you.

Comment: Drush updb only picks up hooks like the one from my example. So you can use this to delete fields for example.